# Correlation between 2 lists of tuples

Tags: python, scipy, correlation, stat

I want to compute the Pearson correlation between two lists of **tuples**. I know that I can compute the correlation between e.g two lists of numbers, by putting them in a dataframe as columns and then just run `df.corr()`. However, I have now lists of tuples (2-element tuples) and I want to be able to compute the correlation between these 2 lists without transforming these tuples into anything else that might cause a loss of information. Is it possible to do that in Python (or anywhere else, as far as this is concerned)?

An example of the 2 lists can be:

```
list1 = [(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)]
list2 = [(10,11),(12,13),(14,15)]
```

Comment: What are the means and standard deviations of your two lists? Without them, you cannot calculate the Pearson correlation.

Comment: @ChristophTerasa I can get the means and the standard deviations of these 2 lists using numpy.mean(list1), numpy.mean(list2), numpy.std(list1), numpy.std(list2). By this, do you mean I should compute the correlation coefficient manually?

Comment: `np.mean(list1)` is 3.5. It flattens the structure, ignoring the fact that you have tuples in there. Is this what you want to do? But you said you don't want to lose information. Before you look for a Python function to do a job, you have to understand yourself what is the job to be done, mathematically.'

Comment: Do you want to treat these as flat lists?